# Decrepyt Password Field

Tags: decrypt

I want to Decrypt the password of Contact portal. But In my Code

> Unrecognized based 64 :* error

occured. I did that things first timei.e didnt understand what is the main problem. maybe my code is wrong or somethings else.

this is my code which i tried to decrypt the password field

```
static void decryptPass(){
    List<Customer_Community_Details__c> portal=new List<Customer_Community_Details__c>([SELECT Id, Password1__c From Customer_Community_Details__c]);
    List<User> users=[SELECT Id, Name ,UserRole.Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = 'Sales Support' OR UserRole.Name = 'Customer Support'];

    for(Customer_Community_Details__c portals : portal)
    {
    if(users !=Null){
       Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
       Blob data = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(portals.Password1__c);
       Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', cryptoKey , data);
       String dryptData = decryptedData.toString();

       System.debug('Printing dryptData '+dryptData);
        portals.Password1__c=dryptData;

    }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't really make sense. It looks like you have a field `Customer_Community_Details__c.Password1__c` that's stored as a Base64-encoded, AES-encrypted blob. Presumably this means your org has the key stored somewhere, likely in a Custom Settings record, and you'd need to go get that key to perform the decryption, but you're generating a *brand new* key

```
   Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
```

that isn't the one used to encrypt this data. At minimum, you have to go get the right key.

It's unclear *where* you're getting that Base64 error, but there are several areas where data formats are potentially being mixed up here, and you must be precise when working with cryptography. If your `Password1__c` field contents aren't valid Base64, that seems like an obvious reason. You're also trying to convert your decrypted data directly to a String, which assumes the original encrypted material *was* a passphrase rather than a key blob - maybe that's true, maybe it's not.

I would be very remiss if I did not point out that storing actual passphrases is very bad security practice, if that's indeed what you are doing, regardless of whether you encrypt them. You should be storing only salted, hashed passwords, and you should never have access to a user's plaintext password.

You state in your comment that you wish to decrypt a field whose type is `Text (Encrypted)`. Your code does not need to (and can't) explicitly decrypt this field, as its encryption is managed by Salesforce. The field's contents are automatically displayed to users who have the permission to view encrypted data, and are available in Apex. Please see [Classic Encryption for Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm#!).

Comment: N.B. I've never found a good solution for storing the key (for enterprise orgs) in a way that even the sysads can't see it (ex creating a private managed package w/ protected custom settings which is a pain). Anything I've missed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - only the managed package/protected custom settings route. Another reason never to store actual passwords, even in encrypted form!

Comment: In my code the field which i want to decreypt is a Text(Encrypted) field type.